# mysql complex join with totals across three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, function, select, join

I have three tables:
payments
orders
products

The payments table has a one to manay connection to orders which breaks out like this

payments: id, name, address, payamentType, orderNumber, promoCode (promocodes override price before they sent into the orders table)

orders: id, productSku, orderNumber, orderQuatity

products: id, sku, title, description, price, inventoryQuantity

so what I need is something like this (a report):

name, address, orderNumber, product1, product1Price, product1OrderQuantity, product2, product2Price, product2OrderQantity, totalProductCost, PromoCode, etc.

So there will be some sum totals.

Products can vary, but I am only pulling data that applies tothe date range of the report, so n-Tier on products, prices, quanties, (aggrigatefinalTotal)

Can this be handled in a complex query?

What type of query or function is this called?

Should I do a function instead and if so, what would the basic function look like.

The results should look like this:
[image]

I should also mention the word_q_o is sku appended with quantity in this order

and _p_o is price for this order (I missed the last one because I was in an hurry but I think you get the gist.

Comment: Are you missing a table that ties products to orders? As far as I can tell there is no way of linking products to an order? In addition the output you have requested only works if there are 2 or less products associated with an order. If there are more products in an order you would need an additional 3 columns per product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be mostly a direct query to get the details, then your report can roll-up the totals as you need.  To get the raw data associated with the payment might be something like

```
select
      p.id,
      p.name,
      p.address,
      p.orderNumber,
      p.promoCode,
      o.id as OrderID,
      o.orderQuantity,
      prod.sku,
      prod.title,
      prod.description,
      prod.price
   from
      payments p
         join order o
            on p.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
            join products prod
               on o.productSku = prod.sku
```

Per comment, attempting a simulated Pivot on multiple columns -- FIXED COLUMNS THOUGH (using alias of the original query as "PQ" (Prequery) but specifically ordering by the order ID so line items are together too.

```
select
      PQ.ID,
      PQ.Name,
      PQ.address,
      PQ.orderNumber,
      PQ.promoCode,
      max( if( PQ.sku = 'umbrella1212', PQ.Price, 0.00 )) as Umbrella1212Price,
      sum( if( PQ.sku = 'umbrella1212', PQ.OrderQuantity, 0.00 )) as Umbrella1212Qty,
      max( if( PQ.sku = 'umbrella1010', PQ.Price, 0.00 )) as Umbrella1010Price,
      sum( if( PQ.sku = 'umbrella1010', PQ.OrderQuantity, 0.00 )) as umbrella1010Qty,
      max( if( PQ.sku = 'rainbootlg', PQ.Price, 0.00 )) as rainbootlgPrice,
      sum( if( PQ.sku = 'rainbootlg', PQ.OrderQuantity, 0.00 )) as rainbootlgQty,
      max( if( PQ.sku = 'rubFlrmts', PQ.Price, 0.00 )) as rubFlrmtsPrice,
      sum( if( PQ.sku = 'rubFlrmts', PQ.OrderQuantity, 0.00 )) as rubFlrmtsQty,
      sum( PQ.Price * PQ.OrderQuantity ) as OrderTotal
   from 
      ( select
          p.id,
          p.name,
          p.address,
          p.orderNumber,
          p.promoCode,
          o.id as OrderID,
          o.orderQuantity,
          prod.sku,
          prod.title,
          prod.description,
          prod.price
       from
          payments p
             join order o
                on p.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
                join products prod
                   on o.productSku = prod.sku
       order by
          p.id,
          o.id ) PQ
   group by
      PQ.ID,
      PQ.Name,
      PQ.address,
      PQ.orderNumber,
      PQ.promoCode
```

Since the name/address/order #/promocode would be the same for all associated line items, of the same "order number", they come along in the group by.  Otherwise MySQL might nag about the columns are not part of an aggregate function (sum, min, max, avg, etc)

Comment: This is close, everything seems to connect, but I am looking to have the productsku with the orderquatity as the row values.  Check out my revised question with a visual example.

Comment: @FrankTudor, what you want is possible, but not practical from any type of reporting... unless you know a fixed MAXIMUM number of items that can be done.  If not, then it would have to be done with dynamic-SQL where you build the command on the fly.  You could pivot, but I've not seen such an example that would pivot multiple fields of each qualifying row.

Comment: Ok sorry I had to add a file I couldn't get the formatting right.

Comment: This would have maybe 10 products max.

Comment: You mentioned pivots do you have an example you can point me to?

Comment: @FrankTudor, revised answer, and you can see how I'm pivoting the row items, but these are SPECIFIC to given "sku" values.

Comment: Ok...this might work...I am going to work this this...Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a query with JOIN payments with orders, and orders with products and you will get one line for each different tuple (name, orders, product)